# completion shows function name and creates documentation in tooltip but documentation not found for scipy

Tags: emacs-jedi

When I complete `sp.integrate.quad` I see a tooltip with the function documentation, but as soon as I accept the completion, the tooltip goes away. I'd prefer to see the the main part of the doc string underneath the function the entire time I'm editing it's arguments. As a stop gap, I tried getting at the documentation another way.  `jedi:show-doc` or `company-jedi-show-doc` look like promising functions for at least re-displaying the docstring information, but they give an error saying they can't find the documentation. Why can't these procedures see the documentation, yet the initial completion tooltip can?  Has anyone used jedi to achieve something close to my desired setup?

Jedi Setup Info:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11180631

Comment: I have the same problem.  Would be cool if this worked.

Answer (score 1):

py-install-directory var must be set correctly for jedi:show-doc.
you can simply set the variable directly in your emacs init file as the following sentance.
`(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa/PYTHON-MODE DIRECTORY")`

or following sentance for the case python-mode package is updated
`(setq py-install-directory (concat "~/.emacs.d/elpa/" (car (directory-files "~/.emacs.d/elpa/" nil "python-mode*"))))`